# Can I use the word "dandy" for a subject other than "man"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Google translates "dandy" as *a **man** unduly devoted to style, neatness, and fashion in dress and appearance.*

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dandy) translates it as *A dandy is a **man** who thinks a great deal about **his** appearance and always dresses in smart clothes.*

Can the word "dandy" also be used for a lady, a girl, or a boy?

Comment: Not for a woman. I wouldn't be that surprised to see it used for a boy.

Comment: Apart from the more recently popular [*That's all **fine and dandy***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fine+and+dandy&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfine%20and%20dandy%3B%2Cc0), I haven't heard this word in decades (but of course, I've often *read* it, in historical novels and such). It's probably still current as an *adjective* in various regional dialects, but I wouldn't really recommend using it as a noun for anyone today - male ***or*** female / child.

Comment: If you still want the "dated" associations, consider ***man-about-town***. Otherwise, I suggest ***playboy***. I don't understand how there could be a "child" version at all though.

Comment: With the flexibility in gender these days, I would think you COULD use dandy for a Woman. Keeping in mind it would imbue her with somewhat masculine qualities. Depending on your character development, it might be an interesting character point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/47155?rskey=iJVWfd&result=1#eid) list numerous uses for:  **dandy**, n.1, adj., and adv.

dress,
animals,
technical and other senses - preceding to things considered neat,
colloq - anything superlatively fine,
nautical,
bantam fowl, and a jug of whiskey

**and** lists an example of a dandy woman:

> 1897   S. Hale Lett. (1919) 319   Mrs. B. was a dandy, she didn't fuss
>   nor worry.

entymonline says of [dandy](https://www.etymonline.com/word/dandy):

> **dandy** is diminutive of Andrew (as it was in Middle English generally). OED notes that the word was in vogue in London c.
>   1813-1819. His female counterpart was a **dandizette** ...

[!]

> (1821) with
>   French-type ending.

The frequency of use is moderate overall. In these times I believe you could use 'dandy' for all manner of things, including genders. Certainly other are. See this recent article *[An Ode to That Rare Creature, the Female Dandy](https://www.thecut.com/2015/03/ode-to-that-rare-creature-the-female-dandy.html)* originating from N.E. America ... where all 'proper' thought arises ... at least in their opinion!

And this from of all places ... Britian:  [Why Female Black Dandies are the Ultimate Rebels](https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/fashion/black-dandies-women-rebel-dandy-lion-project-brighton-photo-biennale-jay-z-kanye-africa-boateng-a7218431.html)

In fact I myself own a right **dandy dog** ... bred in England!

Comment: One can't access the OED without subscription.

Comment: it is gen available with a public library card as i have.

Answer (score -1):

**Quaintrelle** is the female equivalent of *dandy*. Its origin is obscure, but it does sound quite good.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: @M.Mat I guess someone didn't like it very much.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I don't think *quaintrelle* sounds good. It sounds incredibly obscure. There are ***no*** hits in Google books for *quaintrelle* before 1980.  The OED gives one citation for it, in 1450. Nobody seems to have used it in the period when *dandy* was in vogue (the 19th and early 20th century). The Wiktionary page seems completely misinformed.

Comment: And its origin is not that obscure; the OED says it's from the obsolete French word *cointerelle*, which presumably meant the same thing. And this comes from the French word *cointe*, which meant vain, and the suffix *-relle*, which is a diminuitive and would specify a woman.

Comment: @PeterShor: So what's wrong with encouraging a bit of language development? Or must we only use words that have been in use for hundreds of years (i.e. made up by other people)?

Comment: @Ricky: using invented words is perfectly cromulent, as long as people understand what you mean. But somebody really should fix the Wiktionary entry.

Comment: @PeterShor: You? Me? Let's toss a coin.

Comment: I didn't dv, but perhaps the dv-er did so because the answer lacks sources.